# Exclude inner tag and specific label with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is probably a basic question, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Still learning how to use beautifulsoup.

I'm trying to parse HTML that looks like

```
<dl class="">
<div>
<ol>
<li><label>Tournament Name</label>TCG Saturday</li>
<li><label id="tournament_id" data-tournament-id="000002">Tournament ID</label>000002</li>
<li><label>Category</label>TCG: Unlimited</li>
<li><label>Registration</label>12:15PM to 1:15PM</li>
<li><label>Status</label>Complete</li>
</ol>
</div>
</dl>
```

so that only the li tag is read and the label tag is ignored. That is, the resulting text would be

```
TCG Saturday
000002
TCG: Unlimited
12:15PM to 1:15PM
Complete
```

I've tried

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for lis in soup.find_all('li'):
    print(lis.text)
```

but that results in also reading the text of the label tag and cating them together. It also reads a bunch of other text on the webpage and prints it.

```
Tournament NameTCG Saturday
Tournament ID000002
CategoryTCG: Unlimited
Registration12:15PM to 1:15PM
StatusComplete
```

I can also get just the labels using

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for lis in soup.find_all('label'):
    print(lis.text)
```

but that doesn't have the text afterwards (which is understandable).

I don't understand how to parse this HTML so that I can get

1) Just the text in the li tag, excluding the text in the label tag (as in the expected above) or

2) The text in the li tag for a specific label (say, specifying the "Tournament ID" label and getting "000002" back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [BeautifulSoup's](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) Documentation:

`decompose()` removes a tag from the tree, then completely destroys it and its contents:

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<dl class="">
<div>
<ol>
<li><label>Tournament Name</label>TCG Saturday</li>
<li><label id="tournament_id" data-tournament-id="000002">Tournament ID</label>000002</li>
<li><label>Category</label>TCG: Unlimited</li>
<li><label>Registration</label>12:15PM to 1:15PM</li>
<li><label>Status</label>Complete</li>
</ol>
</div>
</dl>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for lis in soup.find_all('li'):
    lis.label.decompose()
print(soup.text)
```

Output:

```
TCG Saturday
000002
TCG: Unlimited
12:15PM to 1:15PM
Complete
```